# ls -la doesn't display correct permission for a mount --bind folder

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, bind-mount

Please read the following steps to understand my problem,

Execute following commands

```
mkdir ~/src
mkdir ~/destination

sudo mount ~/src ~/destination --bind -o ro
```

`src` folder has been bind mounted to `destination` folder. When I view the `destination` folder with nautilus it is read only. But the `ll` command gives same file permission for both `src` and `destination` folders.

What is the reason for this? 
How can I view the actual permission of the 'destination` folder?
How does the nautilus display it as read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

1. Directory permissions.
2. Mount options.

The directory permissions are independent of the fact that the mount was read-only. Hence, `ls` will still list the permissions assigned to the folder, without regards for how it was mounted.

In the same way, if I mount a folder with `noexec`, `ls` will show that the executable files in there are still executable. Mounting the folder with `noexec` (or `ro` in your case) *does not change the permissions on files and directories*.

The file manager appears to be smarter though, and knows that the directory is mounted read-only. It obviously queries more than just the permission bits to find this out.

---

From comments: "In my use case I want to read the mount permission with a shell command".

The command `mount`, without any options, will output all the currently mounted partitions and their mount options:

```
$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=32841600k,nr_inodes=8210400,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=6572324k,mode=755)
(etc.)
```

The mount options are listed in parenthesis.

You may also investigate `/etc/mtab` for the currently mounted filesystems.  This file has the same format as `/etc/fstab`, so you could do

```
awk '{ print $2, $4 }' /etc/mtab
```

to only get the mount points and the mount options, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer. In my use case I want to read the mount permission with a shell command. Then how can I achieve that?

Comment: @DulajAtapattu Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Got a clear understanding and solved my problem by your answer.